# Make a general heat balance solver in python

Tags: python, math, sympy

Playing around with python for a while (mostly icw coolprop) but I'm doing the algebra/calc part by hand (writing the unknowns as explicit functions, integrals etc) and then make use of python to do batch calculation or use coolprop to find properties.
But online I saw people using sympy etc which can solve equations but I can't figure out how to use it for balance equations.

I want to make a function hex() who input variables are the variables seen in the picture below, but I want to get a function that fills in some variables and calculate the unknowns.

So when i give it some thing like this:

> - Q1 = -300
> - Cp1 = 3
> - Cp2 = 2
> - m1 = 5
> - m2 = 3
> - T1a = 100
> - T2a = 20

it returns:

> - T1b = 80
> - T2b = 70

Simple *Q=cp*m*dT* pic with *dT = out-in*, Q is def to be negative if engerie leaves the system

[image]

```
def hex():
  Cp1,T1a,T1b,m1,Q1 = sp.symbols('Cp1 T1a T1b m1 Q1')
  Cp2,T2a,T2b,m2,Q2 = sp.symbols('Cp2 T2a T2b m2 Q2')

  Eq1 = sp.Eq(Q1,Cp1*(T1b-T1a)*m1)
  Eq2 = sp.Eq(Q2,Cp2*(T2b-T2a)*m2)
  Eq3 = sp.Eq(Q1,-Q2)

  Eq1.subs(Q1,-300)
  Eq1.subs(Cp1,3)
  Eq1.subs(T1a,100)
  Eq1.subs(m1,5)

  Eq2.subs(Cp2,2)
  Eq2.subs(T2a,20)
  Eq2.subs(m2,3)

  Anw = sp.solve((Eq1,Eq2,Eq3),T1b,T2b)

  print(Anw)

hex()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code that you could share?

Comment: uhm a lot my first prob is how to make a balans using python so im pretty stuck...

Comment: Put together the equations to be solved and pass them to sympy's solve function.

Comment: Image shows use of derivative which would mean that Q1, Q2, m1, m2 are functions.  Are you using derivatives of these functions in time in the image (i.e. dot above each of their name).

Comment: Q is a heat flow (j/s) and m is a mass flow hence the dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the dots above the symbols are not derivatives because you gave constants as inputs.

You don't have a simultaneous equation. You just have 2 linear equations so its best to solve them non-simultaneously. You also want to input values and get output values. So you don't need to make symbols or do substitutions. They are just arguments to the function.

```py
from sympy import *

def hex(Q1, Cp1, Cp2, m1, m2, T1a, T2a):
    Q2 = -Q1
    T1b, T2b = symbols('T1b T2b', real=True)

    Eq1 = Eq(Q1, Cp1*(T1b-T1a)*m1)
    Eq2 = Eq(Q2, Cp2*(T2b-T2a)*m2)

    T1b_solution = solve(Eq1, T1b)[0]
    T2b_solution = solve(Eq2, T2b)[0]

    print(T1b_solution)
    print(T2b_solution)

hex(-300, 3, 2, 5, 3, 100, 20)
```

the `[0]` after the `solve` gets the first solution.

If you want something where you can input all values except two, then you can do the following:

```py
from sympy import *

def hex(Q1=None, Cp1=None, Cp2=None, m1=None, m2=None, T1a=None, T2a=None, T1b=None, T2b=None):
    unknowns = []
    if Q1 is None:
        Q1 = symbols('Q1', real=True)
        unknowns.append(Q1)
    if Cp1 is None:
        Cp1 = symbols('Cp1', real=True)
        unknowns.append(Cp1)
    if Cp2 is None:
        Cp2 = symbols('Cp2', real=True)
        unknowns.append(Cp2)
    if m1 is None:
        m1 = symbols('m1', real=True)
        unknowns.append(m1)
    if m2 is None:
        m2 = symbols('m2', real=True)
        unknowns.append(m2)
    if T1a is None:
        T1a = symbols('T1a', real=True)
        unknowns.append(T1a)
    if T2a is None:
        T2a = symbols('T2a', real=True)
        unknowns.append(T2a)
    if T1b is None:
        T1b = symbols('T1b', real=True)
        unknowns.append(T1b)
    if T2b is None:
        T2b = symbols('T2b', real=True)
        unknowns.append(T2b)
    
    if len(unknowns) > 2:
        raise ValueError("There are too many unknowns.")

    Q2 = -Q1
    Eq1 = Eq(Q1, Cp1*(T1b-T1a)*m1)
    Eq2 = Eq(Q2, Cp2*(T2b-T2a)*m2)

    solution = solve([Eq1, Eq2], unknowns)

    print(solution)

hex(Q1=-300, Cp1=3, Cp2=2, m1=5, m2=3, T1a=100, T2a=20)
```

The bunch of `if` statements was the fastest way I could think of without using Python's `eval` function or a list as inputs.

Comment: Okay, this indeed works for the given example but isn't versatile. I wanted to make a function that works for every combination of variables (with a sufficient d.o.f). The inputs are probably going to be 2 dict’s and with some other function or some try its looking for the missing variable and solves the equations.

Comment: Thx, I applied some edits to make use of 2 dictionarys (its gonna be part of a simulation tool which uses a dict for every proces stream to store the information) and it worked!